# How can I use a compressed PyTables CArray with R?

Tags: python, r, pytables

with PyTables I have created a compressed CArray:

```
f = tables.openFile('/myPath/test.h5', 'w')
atom = tables.Atom.from_dtype(myNumpyArray.dtype)
ds = f.createCArray(f.root, 'myArray', atom, myNumpyArray.shape, filters=tables.Filters(5, 'blosc'))
ds[:] = myNumpyArray
f.close()
```

How can I load the array into R? I have tried the 'rhdf5' package but get this error:

> Error in H5Dread(h5dataset = h5dataset, h5spaceFile = h5spaceFile, h5spaceMem = h5spaceMem,  : 
>     HDF5. Dataset. Read failed.

Is it possible to use this kind of array in R? If yes, is it possible to load only a part of the array and not the whole array? 
Hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

PyTables has metadata stored. You will need a customized function, see

https://support.bioconductor.org/p/64483

for details.